# Could someone help me figure out the relationship between these two tables?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, many-to-many, one-to-many

[image]

I know that a team will have many games, but my confusion is with the two Foreign keys in the game table referring to the team table id. so would this make it a many to many relationship? because a game has 2 teams and a team has many games?

Comment: Would the FKs make what a many-to-many relationship? Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & you have shown no research effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) PS All the steps are also SO faqs.

Answer (score 2):

> so would this make it a many to many relationship

No. You have *two one-to-many* relationships between teams and games. That's two foreign keys, independent one from the other (although you might want to add a check constraint to forbid a game where the home team is equal to the home team).

Something like:

```
create table game (
     id int primary key,
     ...
     home_team_id int references team(id),
     away_team_id int references team(id),
     ...
     check(home_team_id <> away_team_id)
);
```

Comment: Great thank you! So since they are independent foreign keys they will each have their own relationship

Comment: @DavisHurd: yes, exactly. That's two relationships, represented by two different foreign keys.

Comment: Ok great that really clears things up for me. Also with the check constraint is that just to ensure that the two teams playing in the game cannot be the same team?

Comment: @DavisHurd: yes, that's the purpose of this `check` constraint.